# Erratic cursor behavior. Auto scrolls in browsers, slow to respond and moves erratically

Tags: windows-7, virus, anti-virus

My computer is not unusable yet, but its getting there.  Inside browser cursor moves in an erratic way.  The cursor scroll icon has changed its usual appearance, and it seems to move sometimes on its own.  Its very annoying.  I am running spybot, and malwarebytes but so far they have not found the problem.  Is there any kind of reset I can do on the mouse, cursor within windows?  I went to the windows support site and not really any answers.  I have had this before and it got so bad on another computer I went and bought another one.  Maybe thats the idea. I also have avast why don't they detect this issue? any recommendations?  How do I reset the mouse back to default, default cursor icon etc on windows 7.  thanks

Can't describe but its kind of seems like a virus designed to annoy but not completely keep you from using the computer..

Update: Also notice the following.  Cursor moves at erratic speed. Icon has changed to 4 triangles with dot in center.  Also Icon then changes to dot and downward arrow.  I have not seen these icons before. Does anyone know wha this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the mouse laser or mechanical? if mechanical try cleaning the inside of the mouse trackball

Answer (score 2):

> Icon has changed to 4 triangles with dot in center. Also Icon then changes to dot and downward arrow.

Virus? That simply sounds like you're middle–clicking and activating [AutoScroll](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_autoscroll) in your browser:

[image: 2]

Why would anyone replace their PC because of this? If you use Firefox you can simply turn this off from Options:

[image: 3]

I don't think Chrome or IE offer a similar option though. If this is happening outside your browser as well, check your mouse/touchpad middle–click settings in Control Panel.